# Unable to use id of Facebook Page as value for fb:admins when adding insights for website

Tags: facebook, metadata, facebook-page, facebook-insights

I have added

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="129523843754764" />
```

to the root of votesmart.org, but Debugger Tool fails with the following error:

> Object at URL 'http://votesmart.org/' of type 'profile' is invalid because the given value '129523843754764' for property 'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.

I am using the id of the [Facebook Page](http://facebook.com/projectvotesmart). According to the [Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/), it should work.  I want to allow all of the admins of the Facebook Page to view the Insights for the website.

> If you need to provide access to multiple users then you should create and select a Facebook Page or app.

How can I make sure the admins of the Facebook Page, have access to the Insights for the webpage, and that I can successfully associate the Website with the Facebook Page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Developer Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/):

> ### May 2, 2012
>
> **Removing support to claim Domains using Page ID**  - Originally scheduled for April 1st, 2012
>
> We will remove the ability to claim domains with a Page ID. The recommended option for claiming domains is with an App ID or User ID and existing domains that have been claimed will continue to work fine. After claiming domains, owners are able to view insights or run Domain Sponsored Stories. See the Insights documentation for more on the updated domain claiming flow.

So now, you need to claim it either with a series of user IDs, or an application ID - page ID is no longer available.